# Structured and numbered mathematical notes

Tags: tables, numbering

I need to create a document for typing mathematical definitions and results in compact form. Ideally, the style should follow the picture below (sorry for morphing it!).
[image: Example]
*
 The item of interest is made up of a table with three columns in which:

1. The first contains the id of the item in the following form: #chapter.#number or #section.#number.
2. The second column contains the definition or the statement of the problem.
3. The third column contains additional notes.

All cells are also centered *vertically*.

This is my tentative output, though less than desirable:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,fullpage,amsfonts,amssymb,lipsum,tabularx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[labelsep=endash]{caption}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\newcounter{rowcount}

\setcounter{rowcount}{0}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\noindent
\renewcommand{\figurename}{}

\newcommand{\assertion}[2]{
\noindent\begin{figure}
\noindent \begin{tabular}{m{1cm} m{10cm} | m{4.5cm}}
{\caption{}} & #1 & #2 \\
\end{tabular}   
\end{figure}}

\assertion{The vector $x=[x_1,x_3]$ looks exceedingly promising.]}{Though I have some serious doubts about it.}

\end{document}
```

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a possible scheme:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,fullpage,amsfonts,amssymb,lipsum,tabularx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[labelsep=endash]{caption}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,calc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{assertion}[section] % or chapter
\renewcommand{\theassertion}{\thesection.\arabic{assertion}}

\newcommand{\assertion}[2]{%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}%
  \noindent\refstepcounter{assertion}%
  \makebox[3em][l]{\theassertion}%
  \parbox{.7\textwidth-2em}{#1}%
  \hspace{.5em}\kern-.2pt\vrule\kern-.2pt\hspace{.5em}%
  \parbox{.3\textwidth-2em}{#2}%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}%
}


\begin{document}

\section{Whatever}

\lipsum[2]

\assertion{
  The vector $x=[x_1,x_3]$ looks exceedingly promising.
}{
  Though I have some serious doubts about it.
}

\assertion{
  \lipsum*[3]
}{
  With some comments
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcounter{rowcount}[section]
\renewcommand{\therowcount}{\thesection.\arabic{rowcount}}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\newcommand{\assertion}[2]{%
\refstepcounter{rowcount}%
\noindent\begin{tabular}{m{1cm} m{10cm} | m{4.5cm}}
\therowcount & #1 & #2 \\
\end{tabular}\par}         %\vspace{1em}

\assertion{The vector $x=[x_1,x_3]$ looks exceedingly promising.]}{Though I have some serious doubts about it.}
\assertion{The vector $x=[x_1,x_3]$ looks exceedingly promising.]}{Though I have some serious doubts about it.}
\section{Bla bla}
\assertion{The vector $x=[x_1,x_3]$ looks exceedingly promising.]}{Though I have some serious doubts about it.}
\end{document}
```

You don't need figure here!

it's better to use length like `.75\textwidth` `.2\textwidth` than 1cm, 10cm, 4cm

Comment: Both answers work like a breeze. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @egreg On second thought, nonetheless, I find the font size of mathematical formulas too small when fractions are present.
Moreover, I would like to have the option to decide how to flush the text into the parbox: given that the box on the right is quite small, justification does not work out so pretty when fonts are large.